# Reconfiguring and checking monitors in Postman

Tags: postman

Postman offers the possiblity to create monitors (Launchpad -> View More -> Create a monitor). I know that it is possible to view the list of them from Postman workspace on the web, but is it also possible to check the list of existing monitors directly in Postman Desktop applicaton? Also, is it possible to change the configuration (for example the time interval between checks) of an existing monitor? I've been looking extensively for the first option in Postman Desktop and for the second option both in the Postman Desktop and in the web workspace, but it seems like the answers to both of the questions is no. If this answer actually is "no", then I find it a really strange design decision.

Comment: Could you please accept and upvote the answer

Comment: I have just done that, thanks for the response and sorry for the delay - I had busy schedule and I coudn't properly read and test your response until this moment. Good to know how to edit monitors and that they improved interface so that it is also possible to list them directly from the native application!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update:

Postman v8 is released just now with the fix :

https://www.postman.com/downloads/

Now you can see the same web UI in postman desktop app also

**So you can do both question 1 and 2 through native app**

Answer (score 0):

For first question : **you cannot see it in desktop app**

**For second question:**

[image]

Did you check the postman dashboard in web, you can goto specific monitor and click edit

https://identity.getpostman.com/login?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.getpostman.com%2F%3F